# Random Scrolling issue with Logitech M560

Tags: mouse, scrolling, logitech-mouse

I have a Logitech M560 mouse but I'm not sure this issue is specific to just this Logitech mouse.

Every so often the scroll wheel will become super slow - meaning I will have to scroll a lot to make the page go down or up a tiny bit.

I know this is not a hardware issue because if I shut down the SetPoint software, the scroll immediately works great again but then I lose the functions I set up for all the buttons so I need the software to run.

I also noticed that when this happens, If I open the SetPoint Setting and hit the Apply button (without doing anything else) then the mouse wheel start working again. But having to do this 5-6 times a day is getting annoying.

I have the M560 both a work and at home and I have the same issue on both PCs.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using exactly the same mouse on both PCs, or two mice of the same model?

Comment: They are just the same model. Not the same physical mouse.

Comment: Every now and then I'm having a similar issue with Logitech M705 - but I'm using Linux, so there's no Logitech software installed. Turning the mouse off and back on with the slider on the bottom fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and couldn't find an answer.   I finally decided.. it must be HW and connected a 2nd M560 I had on my daughter's PC.  After I paired it, it worked perfectly.   I was going to get rid of the one I had been using, but instead I unpaired it and paired it again, and it works fine also now.

What I had been doing (a lot!) is opening up setpoint then just clicking apply that that usually fixed it for a while.   This was really bugging me until today!

Answer (score 0):

Opening up Setpoint and then just clicking Ok will fix it, but you have to do this every time you login to Windows again!!
I didn't find a permanent solution yet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).